# How to dynamically construct html tag attriburtes with json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having **(Strigified) json data** in a variable called **test**. I am constructing html elements **dynamically** and also I want **json data** to be inserted in an element attribute.

```
var templateHtml = "":
    $.each(loopValues, function(Key, Value) { // Loops which constructs dynamic data
        var test = '{"type": "page"}';  // this is the json data which need to be appended as data-all attribute value.
        templateHtml = templateHtml.concat("<a data-all="+ test +" href='javascript:;' class='icon' id='TestTt'></a>");
    }
$("#sortable1").html(templateHtml);
```

After executing these lines, when I see the constructed element, It is totally scrambled. How to get a well formatted json data in a element attribute ?

[image]

I **do not want to append json data on attribute using jquery after constructing html**. I want this functionality at html construction time.

I refered 
http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-binding-animation-data-to-elements-with-json/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Any Idea ?

Comment: you missed the `);` to close the `$.each`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code miss some syntax element :

```
var templateHtml = ""; // use ; not :
$.each(loopValues, function (Key, Value) { // Loops which constructs dynamic data
    var test = '"{type": "page"}'; // this is the json data which need to be appended as data-all attribute value.
    templateHtml = templateHtml.concat("<a data-all=" + test + " href='javascript:;' class='icon' id='TestTt'></a>");
}); //close the loop call
```

Then you need to add single quotes around your test variable when you append it. I suggest you choose where to use single quotes or doubles and stick to the choice permanently. I personnally use double quotes in HTML and single quotes in JS :

```
var templateHtml = '';
$.each(loopValues, function (Key, Value) { // Loops which constructs dynamic data
    var test = "{type: 'page'}"; // this is the json data which need to be appended as data-all attribute value.
    //since its JSON i use single quote inside but double outside.
    templateHtml = templateHtml.concat('<a data-all="' + test + '" href="javascript:;" class="icon" id="TestTt"></a>');
});
```

[FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/HtW6d/)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your json in DOM without `data-` attribute, just use:

```
$("#sortable1").html("<a href='javascript:;' class='icon' id='TestTt'></a>");
$( "#sortable1 > a" ).data( 'all', test );
```

According to jQuery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) API. Data value can be any JavaScript type.

To get this JSON you will need just to write:

```
console.log( $( "#sortable1 > a" ).data( 'all' ) );
```

**UPDATE:**

But better is to add data at creation proccess:

```
$.each(loopValues, function(Key, Value) { // Loops which constructs dynamic data
    $( "#sortable1" ).append( $( "<a/>" ).addClass( "icon" ).data( "all", {"type": "page"} ).attr( "id", "TestTt" ) );
});
```

Comment: I am another query? After loop is executed all the contents are added to html. I want to construct the attribute with json at the html (templateHtml) construction time.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is creating elements with jQuery with json as parameters.

For example creating a simple table

```
var $table = new $('<table>', { 'cellpadding' : '5', 'cellspacing' : '4' });
var $tr = new $('<tr>');
var $td = new $('<td>', { 'class' : 'test' });
$td.text('cell contents');
$tr.append($td);
$table.append($tr);

$('body').append($table);
```